# How to save the memory, pid and process using python

Tags: python, dictionary, process, subprocess

How to save the memory, pid and process using python

```
import psutil    
tasklist=['firefox']
out=[]
for proc in psutil.process_iter():
    if any(task in proc.name() for task in tasklist):
        out.append([{'pid' : proc.pid, 'name' : proc.name()}])
for o in out[:]:
    print(o)
name = [j['name'] for i in out for j in i]
print (name)
```

Retrieve memory usage and Cpu usage

```
pmap 413 | tail -n 1

total          2987968K
```

413 is firefox pid

```
 ps -p 413 -o %cpu,%mem

%CPU %MEM
 0.1  3.2
```

How to add memory usage and CPU usage to dictionary
Desired output

```
[{'pid': 413, 'name': 'firefox','cpu':0.1, 'mem':3.2 }]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`Process`](https://psutil.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#process-class) instance has a respective methods presenting cpu/memory usage percentage:

```
...
out.append([{'pid' : proc.pid, 'name' : proc.name(),
                     'cpu': proc.cpu_percent(), 'mem': proc.memory_percent()}])
```

https://psutil.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#psutil.Process.cpu_percent